# segmentation fault on a test of value of variable

Tags: c

I don't understand why there is a segfault on :
 while (((*buf)!= ' '))
I would to store a content of a an array in N others array's (N number of thread), but when I store the content of buff I won't to cut a word.
I don't understand why there is a segmentation fault when I test the value of *buf??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGHT 10

void *count_func(void *arg)
{

}
    int main (int argc, char **argv){

        pthread_t *tids;
        char * buf, * save;
        ssize_t cpt;
        int i, j, fd, count, size, decoup;

        if (argc <2 )
        {   
            printf("\n usage : %s [nom_du_fichier] \n ", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }

        fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);

         //taille du fichier
        size = lseek (fd,0,SEEK_END);
        printf("\ntaille du fichier : %d octets\n",size);
        lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET); // repositionement du pointeur au début du fichier.

        count = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
        count = (count < 1) ? 1 : count;
        char *tabs[count];

        buf =(char *)malloc(size);
        while ((cpt=read(fd,buf, size)) > 0){
            printf("lect en cours \n");
        }
        save=buf;
        while((*buf)!= '\0'){
        printf("carc: %c \n", *buf);
        buf++;
        }

        // répartion des données de buf sur N sous tableau: N correspandant aux nbr
        // de threads
        for (i=0; i< count; i++){
            tabs[i]= (char *) malloc ((size/count)+ MAX_WORD_LENGHT);
        }  
       buf= save; // on sauvgarde l'adresse du début du tableau.
        for (i=0; i<count; i++){
            for (j=0; j<=(size/count); j++, (*buf)!= '\0'){
                    if (j != (size/count)){
                       printf("j:%d \t", j);tabs[i][j] = *buf;        
                       buf++;
                    }else {
                    if (isspace(*buf)){
                        printf("cond 1\n");
                        break;
                    }else{
                       while (((*buf)!= ' ')){ tabs[i][j]= *buf; buf++; j++;}
                        printf("cont: %c \t ", *buf);
                        printf("cond 2\n");
                        break; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        for (i=0; i< count; i++){
            for (j=0; j< (size/count)+1; j++){
            printf("value of tabs[%d][%d] is : %c \n", i, j, tabs[i][j]);
            }
        printf("tabs: %d done \n", i);
        }

        decoup = (size-1)/count;
        tids = (pthread_t *)malloc (sizeof(pthread_t) * count);

        if(tids == NULL)
        {
            printf("main: failed to allocate tids \n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(fd);
        buf=save;
        free(buf);
       // free(tabs[0]); free(tabs[1]);free(tabs[2]);free(tabs[3]);
       // free(tids);
        return 0;
    }

    // vim: filetype=cpp:expandtab:shiftwidth=4:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4
```

Comment: Check for errors, failed `lseek` call, failed `malloc` call, failed `open` call, etc.

Comment: these syscalls works, i test them , but i delte the code of the test.

Comment: Also, that reading loop is not very productive, as the `read` function will overwrite the same data over and over again. *And* you don't check for end-of-file (which happens when `read` returns `0`).

Comment: gdb tell me that the segfault are caused by this line while (((*buf)!= ' ')){ tabs[i][j]= *buf; buf++; j++;}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg can you tell me how can i read the content of a file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go beyond the null terminating character of `buf` unless it finds a space character before.

```
while (((*buf) != ' '))
```

Modify to this

```
while (*buf && *buf != ' ')
```

If there is no null-terminating char in the buf or if there is but you want to read beyond that then check that you didn't go beyond the size of the buffer. E.g.

```
while (j < size && *buf != ' ')
```

Also, `lseek` is not an efficient way to get the size of a file to allocate memory, as you have to go from the start of the file to the end and back to the start again to be able to read. Have a look at [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

Comment: *What* null-terminator? The buffer is never terminated in any way at all, unless the contents of the file the OP read contains the null-terminator. It's probably this that causes the problem though.

Comment: the segfault disappear  but I don't understand why the content of *buf is empty?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for pointing it out. I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: my input file is :123456789abcdefgh
normally the program will copy this in only one tabs and not four , but the output is not correct